# Check the entry after the user has entered a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a graphical interface using Tkinter with Python 3.4. In my script, I am using ttk.Entry to generate a input space where the user can enter a value.

Is it possible to do an action when the user has finished tipping e.g. call a function? I though about using a button if it was not possible.

Here is a extract of the code:

```
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Enter your data path", font=('Times', '14', 'bold italic')).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)

path_frame = StringVar()
input_path_frame = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=100, textvariable=path_frame)
input_path_frame.grid(column=2, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky=(N))
```

I would like to have a event when the 'input_path_frame' is fullfill.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  What does your existing code look like?

Comment: What do you mean by when the user has finished typing? How do you know when they've finished typing? If you want to get the contents of the text box you can do `input_path_frame.get()`

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried nothing in term of functionality. I did only the graphical part. I don't find how to do something. I have no bugs.

Comment: @Farhan.K : this is exactly my question. I add the idea that the field go from selected to unselected. I don't find anything rely to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `FocusOut` event manager function. This event-manager would execute as soon as the user has finished typing in the field and moved to something else:

```
input_path_frame.bind( '<FocusOut>',
    lambda e, strvar=path_frame: check_field(e, strvar)
  )
# check_field function would be executed as soon as the focus leaves the field
```

Here `check_field` function would be used to check if the `input_path_frame` field is empty or not.
.
It would be something like this:

```
def check_field(e, strvar):
  # do stuff
  # check if empty
  # run tests etc
  return strvar.get()
```

If you want to get result keys simultaneously, you can nest two event managing functions like `<FocusIn>` and `<Key>`. And can unbind the `<key>` at `<FocusOut>`:

```
input_path_frame.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: key_bind_func)
input_path_frame.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e: key_unbind_func)
```